# Vout = 12V, Iout= 15A, 180 W Switching regulator

Tags: power-supply, dc-dc-converter, buck

I have experience of designing DC-DC converter upto 5A.

But now for one of my application, I need to design circuit with following specs:

Vin  = 24 - 25 V,
Vout = 12V,
Iout = 15A,
Pout = 180W

So, Is there any switching regulator capable of such high power rating?

( Any application note will extend my knowledge for High Power Design )

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Search Digikey they have many. http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/Q36SR12017NRFA/941-1572-ND/3507450

Comment: @Axis, I have to design it at my own. Any suggestion?

Comment: Voting to close as this is a shopping question, but... There are many switching controllers that (at least on paper) can easily do this; have you done any parametric searching on various manufacturer websites?

Comment: It's not shopping question. I am asking for device which can be used so that I can get a point where I can start my design.

Comment: Why not just parallel 3 12.25V/5A/62W converters with 0.05 ohm series resistors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your experience at 5Amps .Run several together if you are happy with your 5A products.You have heard words like "polyphase  ,Interleave ,Ripple cancelling ,Split phase etc " They all do the same thing and you wont have an EMC suprise assuming your 5A ones are quiet.There are chips that do this if you want to use a chip .Your power components will be the same as your 5A product which eases stocking problems .I am assuming that your 5A product is SMD and automaticly assembled so the increase in parts count wont be a problem .What I am suggesting is nothing new and is often done on computer core supplies.

Answer (score 1):

One Buck regulator will do the work, go for a synchronous Buck to minimize losses maybe. Another option is running the Buck at DCM. You have to pay attention on the ratings of the semiconductors. There is plenty of off the shelf controllers that are able to do that.

Comment: Thanks. Can you recommend a part which you mentioned?

Comment: @Electroholic have a look at: http://www.ti.com/product/tps40170